# Group by with multiple and nullable columns, C# Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a list in c# as the following:

```
COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4    COL5    COL6    COL7
----    ----    ----    ----    ----    ----    ----
1       8635    16      NULL    Design  64      Device type 
1       8635    16      NULL    Design  65      OS  
1       8635    16      NULL    Design  66      Form factor
1       8635    16      NULL    Design  67      Dimensions
----    ----    ----    ----    ----    ----    ----        
1       8635    17      NULL    Design1 64      Device type 
1       8635    17      NULL    Design1 65      OS  
1       8635    17      NULL    Design1 66      Form factor
1       8635    17      NULL    Design1 67      Dimensions
```

How can I get the following result with linq?

```
Group1:
Keys: 
    1       8635    16      NULL    Design
Items:
    64      Device type
    65      OS
    66      Form factor
    67      Dimensions

Group2:
Keys: 
    1       8635    17      NULL    Design1
Items:
    64      Device type 
    65      OS  
    66      Form factor
    67      Dimensions
```

I've done it as the following, but it returns just one group with 8 items:

```
var groupedItems = myDataList
                .GroupBy(q =>
                    new
                    {
                        q.Col1,
                        q.Col2,
                        q.Col3,
                        q.Col4,
                        q.Col5
                    }).ToList();
```

Actual class to use in `group by` is a View in Entity Framework, I wrote 7 columns of it.
I want to group it by 7 first columns: `ObjectId`, `DeviceId`, `DeviceSpecificationCategoryId`, `DeviceSpecificationCategoryIsHidden`, `DeviceSpecificationCategoryName`, `DeviceSpecificationCategoryPersianName`, `DeviceSpecificationCategoryOrderNumberInDevicePage`

```
[EntityFlag]
public partial class DevicePresentationView : BaseEntity
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ObjectId { get; set; }
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DeviceSpecificationCategoryId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> DeviceSpecificationCategoryIsHidden { get; set; }
    public string DeviceSpecificationCategoryName { get; set; }
    public string DeviceSpecificationCategoryPersianName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DeviceSpecificationCategoryOrderNumberInDevicePage { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DeviceSpecificationItemId { get; set; }
    public string DeviceSpecificationItemName { get; set; }
    public string DeviceSpecificationItemPersianName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> DeviceSpecificationItemIsHidden { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DeviceSpecificationItemOrderNumberInDevicePage { get; set; }
    public string DeviceSpecificationItemDescription { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> DeviceSpecificationItemIsPrimary { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> DeviceSpecificationItemIsEssential { get; set; }
    public string DeviceSpecificationItemUnitName { get; set; }
    public string DeviceSpecificationItemUnitPersianName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DeviceSpecificationItemValueTypeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> DeviceSpecificationValueId { get; set; }
    public string DeviceSpecificationValue { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> DeviceSpecificationNumericValue { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DeviceBenchmarkCategoryId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> DeviceBenchmarkCategoryIsHidden { get; set; }
    public string DeviceBenchmarkCategoryName { get; set; }
    public string DeviceBenchmarkCategoryPersianName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DeviceBenchmarkCategoryOrderNumberInDevicePage { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DeviceBenchmarkCategoryParentId { get; set; }
    public string DeviceBenchmarkCategoryDescription { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DeviceBenchmarkItemId { get; set; }
    public string DeviceBenchmarkItemName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> DeviceBenchmarkItemIsHidden { get; set; }
    public string DeviceBenchmarkItemPersianName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DeviceBenchmarkItemOrderNumberInDevicePage { get; set; }
    public string DeviceBenchmarkItemDescription { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> DeviceBenchmarkItemIsPrimary { get; set; }
    public string DeviceBenchmarkItemUnitName { get; set; }
    public string DeviceBenchmarkItemUnitPersianName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DeviceBenchmarkItemValueTypeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> DeviceBenchmarkValueId { get; set; }
    public string DeviceBenchmarkValue { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> DeviceBenchmarkNumericValue { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> DeviceBenchmarkAttachmentId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your query is ok and should return 2 groups. Can you post your class and `myDataList` initialization?

Comment: OK, You can see edited post

Comment: But if you include the  `ObjectId` and `DeviceId` which are the primary key, i.e. unique, then then you'll get exactly the same number of groups as number of rows w/o group by.

Comment: Seeing your actual class the example has become invalid. And it's *impossible* to tell which column you need to do the grouping. I can point at any arbitrary column and tell you to include it in the grouping. Make a [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions) if you want to get any useful input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to group on `Col5` as well for that, you probably missed that:

```
var groupedItems = myDataList
                .GroupBy(q =>
                    new
                    {
                        q.Col1,
                        q.Col2,
                        q.Col3,
                        q.Col4,
                        q.Col5  // notice this
                    }).ToList();
```

Now you can iterate on the result to print or manipulate with Keys and Group against Group.

and it returns result as desired:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but it was my mistake in typing, please see edited post

Comment: how are you displaying them?

Comment: I display them as the following:
`foreach (var group in groupedItems)
{
/* access to group */
 foreach (var item in group)
 {
/* access to item */
 }
}`

Comment: i have ran your code, and it is returning results as desired